# VBA Scheduling Algorithm in MS ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to calculate some schedules on the basis of given dates. Like I have

1. Start Date
2. End Date
3. Weekdays, for example, Monday, Wednesday as a frequency

and I need to calculate 

`weekly
biweekly
triweekly
monthly
quarterly`

dates from the start and end date and also by matching the given weekdays.

For an example

```
Date start = 05/07/2018
Date End = 15/07/2018
Frequency days = Saturday
```

and I need weekly Saturday dates and then biweekly Saturday dates until it reaches to the end date.

I have tried DAYOFWEEK in MS ACCESS VBA which is helping a bit but I need to know the complete solution so I can calculate schedules.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for the `DateAdd` Function.

Comment: @Andre The more you know... `DateAdd` seems rather powerful, actually. Also, wouldn't that be a complete answer?

Comment: I guess you're right. :) @Inarion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work too - I have included input boxes so you can enter start date, finish date, day of the week and  frequency because I don't know how you want that input; also this will store the values in a Table2 Which has a field/column called Dates and then you can retrieve them (I don't know either how do you want to retrieve the dates, if you want to store them etc.)...I hope this helps!:

```
Sub test()

'clear the table2:
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Table2"

Dim DBTest As String
Dim RSTest As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim selectorInitDate, selectorEndDate, DBDate As Date

'Enter Start Date
selectorInitDate = Format(InputBox("Initial Date"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
'Enter Finish Date
selectorEndDate = Format(InputBox("End Date"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
'Enter Day of the Week (example: Saturday)
selectorWeekDay = InputBox("Week Day")
'Enter Frecuency (example: weekly, biweekly, etc)
selectorFreqDays = InputBox("Frecuency Days")

If selectorWeekDay = "Sunday" Then WeekDaySelected = 1
If selectorWeekDay = "Monday" Then WeekDaySelected = 2
If selectorWeekDay = "Tuesday" Then WeekDaySelected = 3
If selectorWeekDay = "Wednesday" Then WeekDaySelected = 4
If selectorWeekDay = "Thursday" Then WeekDaySelected = 5
If selectorWeekDay = "Friday" Then WeekDaySelected = 6
If selectorWeekDay = "Saturday" Then WeekDaySelected = 7

If selectorFreqDays = "weekly" Then Freq = 7
If selectorFreqDays = "biweekly" Then Freq = 14
If selectorFreqDays = "triweekly" Then Freq = 21
If selectorFreqDays = "monthly" Then Freq = 30
If selectorFreqDays = "quarterly" Then Freq = 90


DBDate = Format(selectorInitDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Count = 0

Do While DBDate <= selectorEndDate

    If Weekday(DBDate) = WeekDaySelected Then

        DBTest = "INSERT INTO Table2 ([Dates]) " & _
                    " VALUES (" & _
                    "'" & DBDate & "');"

        CurrentDb.Execute DBTest

        DBDate = DBDate + Freq - 1

        Count = Count + 1

    End If

DBDate = DBDate + 1

Loop

'this retrieves in a msgbox the saturdays found between the two dates you specify:

DBTest = "SELECT * FROM Table2"

Set RSTest = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(DBTest)

If Not RSTest.BOF And Not RSTest.EOF Then

    RSTest.MoveFirst

    Do While (Not RSTest.EOF)

        If Format(RSTest.Fields("Dates").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") >= selectorInitDate And _
        Format(RSTest.Fields("Dates").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") <= selectorEndDate Then

            mthString = mthString & RSTest.Fields("Dates") & ", "

        End If

      RSTest.MoveNext

     Loop

   End If

' (remove last comma)
mthString = Left(mthString, Len(mthString) - 2)

MsgBox Count & " " & selectorWeekDay & "(s) Added" & Chr(43) & mthString

'clear the table2:
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Table2"

End Sub
```

Following your example this should give you how many saturdays you have between two dates in a weekly basis, and which are those dates.

Note: you need to have selected on your reference the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library"

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Just 2 comments
1. what if we have multiple weekdays like Friday|Saturday separated by pipe sign
2. how to select reference the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" I am using MS Access 2016.

Comment: 1. you can extract "Friday" and "Saturday" from the String with the pipe sign and then run the macro; 2. In the visual basic editor you have to select Tools > References... > Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library  - :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works great. There is a problem. Suppose I selected Saturday of the current week and want to get date of Monday for the next week. And you know that next week will start after a day. But in your solution you are adding 7,14,21 and so on. It is taking the date to the future and we can't get that week particular day which are in past. I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: It is adding 7,14,etc after the first find, so if you enter 7/7/2018 which is a Saturday, and select Monday, it should retrieve next Monday which is 7/9/2018.

Comment: yes this is wrong. It should retrieve the current week Monday.

Answer (score 1):

The [DateAdd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function) can do all that.

Air code:

```
d = StartDate
Do While d <= EndDate
    Debug.Print d   ' <-- Output date
    Select Case Interval
        Case "biweekly": d = DateAdd("ww", 2, d)
        Case "monthly" : d = DateAdd("m", 1, d)
        ' etc.
    End Select
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you. DateAdd looks promising. But how I can get date for after 2 weeks the specific day for example Friday. 

E.g. what will be date of Friday after 2 weeks, 3 weeks, 4 weeks etc

Comment: @Aziz, I appended a function for finding the date of the weekday.

Answer (score 1):

For months, you should always add to the original startdate as this could be one of the last days of a month, thus is would offset the dates for months following a month having fewer days. So:

```
Dim StartDate   As Date
Dim EndDate     As Date
Dim NextDate    As Date
Dim Interval    As Long

StartDate = #1/31/2018#
EndDate = #6/30/2018#

Do
    NextDate = DateAdd("m", Interval, StartDate)
    Interval = Interval + 1
    Debug.Print NextDate
Loop Until NextDate >= EndDate
```

will return:

```
2018-01-31
2018-02-28
2018-03-31
2018-04-30
2018-05-31
2018-06-30
```

For starting on a specific weekday, find the first of this, then add intervals as above:

```
Public Function DateNextWeekday( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal bytWeekday As Byte = vbMonday) _
  As Date

' Returns the date of the next weekday, as spelled in vbXxxxday, following datDate.
' 2000-09-06. Cactus Data ApS.

  ' No special error handling.
  On Error Resume Next

  DateNextWeekday = DateAdd("d", 7 - (Weekday(datDate, bytWeekday) - 1), datDate)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you just wanted the bi-weekly dates grouped in 14 day increments beginning with some starting date (first week of the year for example) indate could be the current date or some date you choose or you could just you today().

```
Function biweeklyDate(indate as date) as Date
biweeklyDate = (DateSerial(2021,1,4)-indate) Mod 14 + inDate
End function
```